# Как реализовать процент для калькулятора?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Форумчане, есть необходимость в программе написать калькулятор. Нужно написать кнопку для расчета процента, (+, -, *, /, +/-) - уже написаны... а с процентом, - честно говоря, не понимаю, как его реализовать. Я не прошу написать исходник, подскажите, как его можно реализовать.

Answer (score 3):

А разбирается выражение только из двух чисел?

Как вариант, можно по нажатию на кнопку "%" после второго числа, подставлять вместо второго числа значение

```
ВтороеЧисло = (ЧислоПроцентов*ПервоеЧисло)/100
```

а дальше выполнять нужную операцию.

Если число с процентом было введено после первого числа, но можно просто его делить на 100:

```
ПервоеЧисло = ЧислоПроцентов/100
```

Этот вариант (при использовании "%" в первом числе) используется в калькуляторе в Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

**%** это скорее не операция, это как бы сказать получение результата. Допустим запись в калькуляторе **200-10%** равнозначно записи **200-(200 x 10 x 0.01)=** , т.е. те надо **A операция (A x B x 0.01) =**